# Integrating zxing in ios with cocoapods: multiFormatReader.h is missing and multiFormatOneDReader does not decode

Tags: ios, zxing, cocoapods

I'm getting frustrated trying to integrate zxing to my xcode project with cocoapods. My podfile:

```
platform:ios, '6.0'

pod 'ZXing', '~>2.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~>1.3.1'
```

What works is QRCodeReader and DataMatrixReader, the MultiFormatReader.h File is missing (so #import multiFormatReader.h gives an "not found" error) and the MultiFormatOneDReader doesn't decode anything.

I set the c++ compiler of my project target to default, named my .m file to *mm, and the project target's header search paths are

```
${PODS_ROOT}/Headers
${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/AFNetworking
${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/ZXing
${PODS_ROOT}/ZXing/cpp/core/src/
${PODS_ROOT}/ZXing/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes
```

Any hints what I'm missing here?!

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ZXing 2.2 would solve your problem.